# Converting Character variable into date (lubridate)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, lubridate

I am trying to visualize the frequency of posts within a given sub-reddit, in a time series graph as in [here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/279-plotting-time-series-with-ggplot2.html). However, I believe that I first need to convert my date variable into a date format, and then create a new variable that counts observations by date. I am struggling with the first step, but here is my code below:

Solved this with the proposed solution by Limey:

```
df %>%
  mutate(date=lubridate::dmy(date))
```

## loading packages

```
#Loading packages
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
library(quanteda)
library(stringr)
library(textclean)
library(lubridate)
```

```
sapply(df, class)
     id        post        date
```

"integer" "character" "character"

data output:

```
 id        post        date            
1          yx          25-08-2012
2          xy          25-08-2012
3          zy          25-08-2012
4          aha         26-08-2012       
5          yes         26-08-2012
```

To convert my date variable from character to date format, I did the following:

```
df %>%
lubridate::dmy(date)
```

However, I keep receiving this message "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"

Ideally, I would have a df that looks as follows:

```
id        post        date              observations
1          yx          25-08-2012       3
2          xy          25-08-2012       3
3          zy          25-08-2012       3 
4          aha         26-08-2012       2
5          yes         26-08-2012       2
```

Which I can then visualize as follows:

```
 ggplot(aes(x = date , y = observations)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(vars(key), scales = "free_y")
```

Comment: Your problem is caused by the fact that you haven't wrapped your type conversion in `mutate`.  Therefore, R doesn't know that you want `date` to refer to a column in your data frame rather than the built-in function `date()`.  Solve the problem by writing `df %>% mutate(date=lubridate::dmy(date)) `.  I would also recommend renaming your `date` column.  It's bad practice to use the names of built-in functions as column or object names.

Comment: Yeah, Limey is right - the reason you're getting that specific error instead of a more transparent one is because of the name conflict between `df$date` and `date()`